# Node.JS Error (FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory)

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, wait

I am attempting to make a simple while (true) {} loop, but it waits 1 second before running the code inside it. Basically, I want a system something like this:

> Hello, world!
> (waits 1 second)
> Hello, world!
> (waits 1 second)
> Hello, world!
> (waits 1 second)
> Hello, world!
> (waits 1 second)
> Hello, world!
> (waits 1 second)
> and so on.

But I keep on receiving this error:

> FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

My code:

```
while (true) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(`Hello, world!`)
    }, 1000);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What your code does is schedule timer callbacks repeatedly until it runs out of memory; none of the timers actually has a chance to run. Nothing makes the `while` loop wait for the timer callback to occur. See the linked question's answers for more details.

Comment: @Dan3DTV Yes. Exactly, it is an infinite loop that you are creating and hence it is running out of memory.